# Comparing two maps to see if one is a subset

Tags: c++

I am checking two maps of  that is case sensitive and if duplicates occur in the note_map the mag_map must be greater than or equal.

```
void checkMagazine(vector<string> magazine, vector<string> note) {
    std::map<string, int> mag_map;
    std::map<string, int> note_map;

    for(auto it : magazine){
       mag_map[it]++;
    }

     for(auto it : note){
       note_map[it]++;
    }
```

I would like to check mag_map to see if it holds the keys in note_map and I also want to see if there are enough occurrences in the mag_map to make the note.

Comment: *if duplicates occur in the note_map* -- A `std::map` does not store duplicate keys.

Comment: [The <algorithm> library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) has all sorts of fun tools that may be able to help you

Comment: He means if duplicates from the `note_vector` are indicated by a number bigger than one in `note_map`. The code in the question looks like a sensible framing for the question. To bad it does not show any effort on solving the problem by the OP.

Comment: To add -- tools such as `std::set_intersection`

Comment: Do you need those two `std::map` containers anyway for other reasons, or would a different solution working with the original `std::vector` containers be good?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah but that requires that both arrays are sorted which in this case they are not. And sorting would increase the time complexity. It's one solution but not the one I'd use.

Comment: [Ranged for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) give you the *value type* of the container, which for a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a `std::pair<const KeyType, DataType>`. And for a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) it's the actual data inside the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're off to a good start. Now you just need to iterate through `note` and check if each word is present in `mag_map`. If it is, then you also need to check if the word occurs *at least* as many times in `mag_map` as it does in `note_map`. If at any iteration one of the conditions is not true, then you can break from there and print "No", because the ransom note cannot be made from the magazine.

Hint: use [`find(Key)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) to search and [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) to get the count.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to incorporate the find method and ill let you know how it goes.